# Where could a base be located so that no-one can reach it?

Tags: post-apocalypse

Before the apocalypse a base was created to preserve and protect the highest members of society, including the president, Vice President, high ranking military officials, scientists, etc. The population of this base will be 6,500 citizens and 1,000 maintenance workers to keep it running.

My question is: **where could the base be located so that it can fit these criteria?**

- They have to be able to collect water (they can filter salt water)
- They have to be able to make their own power, it doesn’t matter what kind they use.
- It has to be somewhere where common folks can’t access it.
- The apocalypse was a nuclear war, so it has to be somewhere that an enemy wouldn’t want to target.
- They remain there for 500 years (even though they could leave if the want)

-The population doesn’t Grow bigger than 7,500 because the kill everyone at age 30, and couples of two can only have two kids, after which they are sterilized,keeping the population the same. 
-Most Of The education, maintenance, and food growing is down by robots, so people don’t have to do much besides breeding.
-The entire base is controlled by a supercomputer who was programmed to keep them locked in until it’s safe, but it malfunctioned, so they are locked in forever

Where could they put the base?

This takes place in North America, which means they are limited to areas in or around the continent. They have about 15 years to plan and build the base, and they have present day technology.

Comment: You know that nuclear fallout stops being dangerous after about 6 to 8 weeks right?

Comment: That’s not the reason they stay for so long

Comment: Okay, so there are problems with this question.  First: what country are we talking about? How much warning was available before the nuclear attack? Does it have to be ready to generate power or do they have time to plan? What land masses are they limited to? There is so much information missing from this question. And that is assuming we are talking about our current world.

Comment: If "**no-one can reach it**" then, by definition, your 6500 highest members of society and their 1000 peons... can't reach it.

Comment: No they are able to reach just not intruders

Comment: Need more tags and details. Do you want only 'realistic' answers or would more sci-fi ones be acceptable? When is this happening? Now, 10 years in the future, 50 years, etc.

Comment: More sci-go ones are acceptable, and this is happening in the mid 2050s

Comment: Somewhere in the Rockies? If you keep thermal leakage down, it would be both inaccessible and nearly impossible to spot

Comment: Bottom of atlantic ocean, near volcanic activity. Geothermal generators, kelp farms, large warehouse, fish tanks. Can be reached by nuclear submarines. Originally built for prolonged space isolation research.

Comment: You're missing a lot of criteria for a believable scenario.  I'm going to list a few in a series of comments.  Please edit your question with your responses (you should never make people read all the comments to get all the updates).

Comment: [The average American eats about one ton of food annually](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2011/12/31/144478009/the-average-american-ate-literally-a-ton-this-year) and you need to have enough food for 7,500 people for 500 years.  That's either 3.7 million **tons** of food stored up front or the ability to produce it underground as you go.  Underground food production is usually iffy, so we're really talking about massive (massive) food storage.

Comment: [Populations double about every 60 years](https://www.quora.com/How-often-does-the-world-population-double) which means unless you're imposing brutal and inhumane limitations on child bearing &mdash; which you're obviously going to need &mdash; you have the very real potential of needing to house **1.9 MILLION PEOPLE** (your food requirement just exploded).  Or, do you intend to sterilize/euthanize/do something drastic?

Comment: Your community will require police, judiciary, a town-level government (not a nation-level government, which is what you're protecting), medical, education, utilities (water, electricity, sewage, trash, etc.), manufacturing (a HUGE issue that I'll get to in a moment), food storage & production, pharmaceutical storage & production, entertainment, transportation, even janitors.  *I've skipped a TON of items on this list.*  Exactly how many people are we really trying to save?  Because all 7,500 people are needed to operate your little community.

Comment: Manufacturing means raw materials.Lumber, metal, minerals, hydrocarbons, more minerals, and a boat load of water.  [Using a water reference from San Diego](http://aquaholics.ucsd.edu/who-uses-the-water/index.html) we see that 80% of water usage in California is agriculture.  Of the 20% used by everything else, half is used by regular citizens, a quarter by industry, and a quarter by everything else.  My point is, you need a lot of water &mdash; especially as you get to that 1.9 million person mark.

Comment: Finally, people are unreasonable. You're going to have people clamoring to get out of their little sunless sanctuary within weeks. Not a lot, mostly teenagers, but with every passing day there will be more. Whatever reason you have for keeping people inside for 500 years won't, and can't, be reason enough because people are unreasonable. I'm not saying you can't base your story on it (irreversibly time lock the doors, hang the idiot who mistakenly set it for 500 years instead of 500 days), I'm saying that when it does open, it's going to explode like a tin can full of botulism.

Comment: @JBH All those comments would perhaps be better as proper answer than comments.  I know it's not a direct answer to the question, but it's on point as to why the question has arguably no reasonable answer and I think that's a reasonable answer in many cases.

Comment: @StephenG, in many cases I did make such a list of comments into an answer.  But this question has merit and I would like to see it more thoroughly addressed.  Thucydides' answer is excellent (I upvoted it) as it could accomodate many of the comments I made and I don't want to detract from it or the others.  But, this time, I'd like to see the OP flesh out the issues he/she hasn't thought through so that everything's improved.

Comment: @JBH: you have some very good questions that I hadn’t thought about. For the first one, this is a world where they have advanced androids, which can do medical, janitoring, education and everything else. Second, about the population, it is very dark. The kill off everyone who is over 30 years old ( yes likeLogan run) and every couple of two people are only allowed to have 2 children, keeping the population the same. And the reason the stay for 500 years is because an AI controls the base, and it was programmed to not let anyone leave until it was safe, but it malfunctioned and locked them in

Comment: So they were trapped there permanently

Comment: Please edit your question with the responses.  This makes it simpler for people to find the clarifications before they answer. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, I’m sorry I forgot to add these

Comment: Twenty generations of humans over 500 years runs to a bit under 150,000 corpses. Any underground solution will seem to have rather monumental trash and sewage disposal problems to avoid being buried by their own wastes.

Comment: They eat the dead corpses, or “recycle” them

Comment: So with your plan, they need to kill the president and the vice-president? You say you need people in the base but then goes on to say they are only there for breeding and machines run the place. Why do they need people and why would they want to build the base in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

Large shelters already exist in salt domes sited in various places across the United States. Because of the nature of the rock salt, the most common use is as archival storage areas for sensitive items like film, since the temperature is constant (due to being underground and away from surface fluctuations) and the air is at a constant, if low humidity, since the salt will absorb humidity.

Simply doing some gradual work to expand and "update" or "modernize" the facilities would probably not arouse too much attention, and bringing drilling equipment to sink deep boreholes below the salt dome to access water and geothermal energy should also be relatively unobtrusive.

[image]

*Typical salt dome*

Many salt domes are found in the southern US and Texas, so the only real sticking point is how would a large number of people (thousands in your account) suddenly be transported to the dome and disappear during a crisis (and especially when would their sudden disappearance *not* become the trigger for the crisis to become "hot").

[image]

*Where you can find salt domes*

Answer (score 6):

Your requirement that the enemy not want to target is a **major** problem--there's no way to hide such construction.  When you combine it with the common guy can't get there you're talking about major construction in the middle of nowhere.  That's going to draw a missile.  Your problem is **almost** insolvable.

However, I see one option.  Don't put it somewhere.

Rather, your base is a nuclear-powered, shallow-submerging submarine.  It's in the ocean, it heads south and affixes itself under a major piece of floating antarctic ice.

Power:  Nuclear.  Check.
Water:  Desalination.  Check.
Isolation:  You need a submarine, something the common man doesn't have.  Check.
Targeting:  While the enemy certainly knows of it's existence they don't know where it is and thus can't target it.  Check.
500 years:  No.  Whatever they are under will melt before then.  By then, though, they don't need to hide like that.  Simply go to shallow water somewhere near the equator (no hurricanes) and wait your 500 years.

Comment: "*Targeting: While the enemy certainly knows of it's existence they don't know where it is and thus can't target it.*"  The USSR/Russia have been developing ASW since the 1950s.  They *will* know at all times where a submarine large enough to fit a small town is at.  http://gentleseas.blogspot.ca/2012/08/satellite-detection-of-submarines.html

Comment: A submarine for 7500 people... that alone worth a novel or a movie!

Comment: A sub for 7500 people for 500 years + child births.  A sub for 1.9 million people.  It's a clever idea, but doesn't meet the OP's needs.

Comment: @Alexander I think it is called "2012"?

Comment: I disagree that they will always know where it is.  They'll know it's somewhere under the antarctic ice but that's not good enough to target it.  Once it's hidden in the ice the only detection that will see it is magnetic anomaly--and that's very short range.

Answer (score 2):

This is a deeper version of a similar underground system of bunkers beneath Washington, DC. Therefore, the simplest place for your proposed bunker would be a deeper and bigger version of the existing bunker for top-level government survivors, possibly, a mile deep and below the nation's capital.

To complete their inaccessibility a mechanism needs to be in place to prevent unwanted people gaining entry to the base. Explosive demolition of the entry paths and/or lift shafts (of course, you guys call them elevators) can do the trick.

The base is basically only a bigger and better version of an existing facility. Best to simply go deeper and bigger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such place, even aside from the impossible food requirements.  If they can get to some place to build the base, other people can get there later on, and 500 years would give them plenty of time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a massive warren of lead-encased tunnels and chambers deep inside the crust. Water could be fed via natural springs and geothermal vents could be used to generate power. The entrance to the base could be a narrow tunnel bored into the heart of a mountain and guarded by heavy ballistic steel missile resistant pneumatically-controlled doors. The doors would open into the mountain's heart, and would have to be reached by navigating a labyrinth of tunnels, with defenses, bored into the mountain. The labyrinth would only be accessible by a well disguised and inconspicuous entrance built into the mountainside, maybe even one of those sliding boulder ones. The mountain could have natural metallic deposits which would suppress any type of comm leak.